local gitea runner service can not find gitea server
when i run the command actions/checkout@v4 i get an error
I a gitea docker container running on ubuntu.
this is the docker compose file:
services:
  gitea:
    image: gitea/gitea:latest
    container_name: gitea
    environment:
      - USER_UID=1000
      - USER_GID=1000
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - gitea-data:/data
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"   # Gitea web interface
      - "222:22"       # SSH for Git access
    networks:
      - gitea_network

volumes:
  gitea-data:
    external: true

networks:
  gitea_network:
    driver: bridge
    external: true

And a gitea action runner on a different docker (on the same server).
This is the runner docker compose:
services:
  runner:
    image: gitea/act_runner
    environment:
      GITEA_INSTANCE_URL: "http://gitea:3000"
      GITEA_RUNNER_REGISTRATION_TOKEN: "xxxxxxx"
      GITEA_RUNNER_NAME: "Gitea Runner"
    volumes:
      - ./gitea_runner:/data
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    networks:
      - gitea_network

networks:
  gitea_network:
    driver: bridge
    external: true

Now, when i run the command: uses: actions/checkout@v4 under the file '.gitea/workflows/ci.yaml' in the repository.
i get the error :
fatal: unable to access 'http://gitea:3000/testuser/first_gitea_test/': Could not resolve host: gitea 
What am i doing wrong?
Why is the runner not recognizing Gitea?
should it not have recognized it already? the runner already recognize the gitea server in the docker compose (otherwise the runner will not execute)
